# How to Mapp Classes in Java and Flex

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, red5

i would like to ask you the following qeustion:

is ist Possible to  user Java Classes in Action script like in the following example?

Java:

MyClass.login("Username","Password");

ActionScript:

MyClass.login("Username","Password");

I need to call the Class in Java to use the Class in Actionscript.
The Goal is to write in ActionScript MyClass.login("user","pw"); an the Java Class make the Action.
Is that Possible? I heard something of Remote Class Stuff but i dont think that's the right think.

I'm working on a Red5 Server who will do the Login Stuff and gives only a User Value Object back which will be proffed if is null or not

syr for my bad english, Hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible from ActionScript to call a method in Java. To connect both project you can use BlazeDS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlazeDS

Here you can find a manual which explain step by step how to do a small example : [blazeDS example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder_blazeds.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I even know BlazeDS but i cant use it. Is there any other option for this ? 
The Fact is that i BlazeDS is not full free. The Alternative would be GraniteDs but im looking for another way. Is there one or should i use this Option?

Comment: Why can't you use BlazeDS?

Comment: Both, graniteds and blazeds are under LGPL licence, so if you can use one, there is no a problem with the other.

Comment: ahh okay ill try it. Thank you very much.
Do BlazeDS and GraniteDS support sinlge Sessions ? Afaik there are only Scopes who support a group of Client